# how to change :class in html tag to jsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

**<html :class="{ 'theme-dark': dark }" x-data="data()" lang="en">**

Forgot password - Windmill Dashboard

```
      <img aria-hidden="true" class="object-cover w-full h-full dark:hidden"
        src="../assets/img/forgot-password-office.jpeg" alt="Office" />
      <img aria-hidden="true" class="hidden object-cover w-full h-full dark:block"
        src="../assets/img/forgot-password-office-dark.jpeg" alt="Office" />
    
    
      
        <h1>
          Forgot password
        </h1>
        
          your text mail
          <input
            class="block w-full mt-1 text-sm dark:border-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700 focus:border-purple-400 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-purple dark:text-gray-300 dark:focus:shadow-outline-gray form-input"
            placeholder="Jane Doe" />
        

        <!-- You should use a button here, as the anchor is only used for the example  -->
        <a class="block w-full px-4 py-2 mt-4 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-center text-white transition-colors duration-150 bg-purple-600 border border-transparent rounded-lg active:bg-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-purple"
          href="./login.html">
          Recover password
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to change this code into JSX and use in my NEXT JS Project

Comment: You probably need to reformat your code block. Some tags are missing

Answer (score 1):

I think you provided code is based on VueJS.

If is it right, please try like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

  return (
    <html className={dark ? 'theme-dark' : ''}>
      {/* Rest of your JSX code */}
    </html>
  );
}
```

use `className` instead of :class and then you can use ternary operator to use `dark` variable.